# 315GLE dimmer dont switch on the lights

Tags: wiring, light-fixture, dimmer-switch

I bought a new dimmer because I believe the old one is broken.
Spotlights are turning (dimming) off after 2 seconds (on the old dimmer). I believe the coils are broken.

The old dimmer is called **315 GLE 2P** from **ELKO** and the new dimmer is called **E:ZO dimmer RS16/315 GLE**.
Im not sure if I bought the right one, because seemed a bit different on the symbols.
I am wondering if I can use it anyway?

[image]

The question I have is where the wires go from the old one to the new.
Can I wire the dimmer the same as before? Like sine+arrow to sine+arrow, L(up) to L, N(up) to L, and N(down) to B? Or how can I get lights to work as before?

[image]

*(manual diagram for the new dimmer)*

The dimmer is wired to the spotlights. I do not have access to the interior of the wall, so I dont know where the wires go. I measured ~220V on the Live wires to the other wires. And the dimmer seems to be working when I turn it on and off (according to my multimeter), but the lights won't turn on. Any help appreciated.

*(I unfortunately dont have the wiring or manual for the old dimmer)*

Comment: Does the New dimmer come with any kind of manual? Can you share pictures of what the wiring around the dimmer looks like?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau The manual does not say much. But I have added the wiring diagram there. However I dont understand any of it except the L and N which is 220V positive and negative right? And the old dimmer was here when I moved in, so Im unable to find the manual for it.

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau Ive improved the first picture and added the wire colors. I basically wired it the same as the old one and it doesnt work. I was just guessing.

Comment: @NaturalNumberGuy  Guessing when working with electricity can be a shocking experience with 120 volts.  With 220 it can be the last guess you take.  Do not guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new dimmer you bought is designed to be used in a 3-way switch setup (with another switch also controlling the lights.

The way to wire it up is to connect only the blue wires to the switch, with the one going to the lights on the connector with the wavy symbol and the other one on one of the connectors with an L.

The two brown wires should be connected together with a wire nut or similar. They do not need to be connected to the dimmer.

Comment: Yey. It worked. I wouldn't have figuring this one out by myself.

Comment: I am not quite sure and might be mistaken, but I think you have the wire connections opposite.  This looks like UK/Europe wire colours, so blue should be neutral and brown is live.  In the US switching neutral is frown upon since it leaves live power at the light fixture all the time.